# tSQLt simple SELECT statement - what tests do I need? Best practice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt

This is a question about tSQLt / SQL testing best practice.

Assume I have a stored procedure that returns the results of a simple SELECT statement e.g.

```
SELECT
    A.Column1
,   B.Column2
FROM
    TableA AS A
INNER JOIN
    TableB AS B
ON
    A.ID = B.ID
    ;
```

I am thinking about what tSQLt tests to write. The most obvious test would be where I have records in both tables (with matching IDs) and the procedure returns the correct data.

Is that test sufficient? Possibly not, because somebody could change that INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, and the test would still pass, but the behaviour of the stored procedure has now changed.

Therefore should I have tests for when either TableA or TableB is empty, or both tables are empty, that no records are returned? Although I think this is more complete, it smells like overkill to me, and could lead to a frightening number of tests for a SELECT statement with 5 or more tables.

I would appreciate the community's thoughts.

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: Exactly what is your purpose going down this road?  JOIN means only return rows that are in both tables, so that would imply that valid tests are (1) when rows are in both tables, (2) when rows are in one table but not the other, (3) vice versa, and (4) rows are in neither tables.

Comment: Hello Jim. An inner join is required, so it seems to make sense to ensure I have the right tests in place to ensure that an inner join has to be implemented. If anybody changed the join, the tests would fail. My concern is that for complex queries I would require an large number of tests (factorial table count!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is less of ensuring that there is an INNER JOIN. As we don't want to specify exactly how the stored procedure is implemented. We do however want to make sure that the expected results from the stored procedure are always returned as expected.

My test would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyTests.SimpleTests].[test Returns_SimpleTable_Successfully]
AS
BEGIN
    --Arrange
    EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @schemaname = 'dbo', @tablename = 'TableA';
    EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @schemaname = 'dbo', @tablename = 'TableB';

    INSERT INTO TableA (Id, Column1) VALUES (1, 'Value1'),(2, 'Value2')
    INSERT INTO TableB (Id, Column2) VALUES (1, 'Value3'),(3, 'Value4')

    CREATE TABLE Expected
    (
       Column1 NVARCHAR(255),
       Column2 NVARCHAR(255)
    )

    INSERT Expected (Column1, Column2)
    VALUES (N'Value1', N'Value3');

    --Act
    CREATE TABLE Actual
    (
       Column1 NVARCHAR(255),
       Column2 NVARCHAR(255)
    )

    INSERT Actual (Column1, Column2)
    EXEC up_SimpleTest

    --Assert
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'Expected', 'Actual'

END;
```

The stored procedure under test looking like this:

```
CREATE PROC up_SimpleTest
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        A.Column1,
        B.Column2
    FROM TableA AS A
    RIGHT JOIN TableB AS B
        ON A.Id = B.Id;

END
```

This means that if the stored procedure changed to either a LEFT, RIGHT or FULL join. The test will fail as the expected data won't be returned. It does however allow for the stored procedure to change to this and still be valid:

```
SELECT
    A.Column1,
    B.Column2
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE A.Id = B.Id
```

This is why we shouldn't and can't enforce an INNER JOIN is used as there are many other valid methods as to how a query can be implemented.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I didn't mean I required an actual INNER JOIN to be implemented, but that data should only be returned if matching data exists on both sides. If you had a query with multiple tables, would you then have many more tests with combinations of values?

Comment: No, You don't have to do multiple combinations of values for tests. It's all about ensuring the expected data is returned. However, when you fake your tables with data, it's about ensuring the fake data you enter covers those scenarios, so if a join was changed or a new table added, the test would fail. The only time I create more tests, is if my proc has filters. I would have a test for filter X, Y and Z independently being tested or if I want to test different routes through my procs.

Comment: I agree with JBond.  He creates one expected row plus an additional row in each table that will not get returned for an inner join (whether that is ANSI-standard or not).  Any other kind of join would result in additional, unexpected rows.  Given that SQL is set-based, I think it is perfectly reasonable that a single test includes both positive and negative tests - otherwise, given the nature of SQL as a relational language the number of tests could grow exponentially as you add more joins.  I write my tests exactly as JBond describes, adding (typically) one new test for each new join.

Comment: Sorry for the radio silence and than you both for taking the time to reply. I will apply your ideas in future. Many thanks, Ash